# Cложение чисел забраных при парсинге

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Есть сайт - https://parsinger.ru/html/index1_page_1.html
Я спарсил с него цены на часы, и вывел их в консоли. Я хочу сложить полученные числа, но способа кроме как сложить их и занести в переменную я не знаю, я бы хотел сделать это автоматически, даже если бы чисел было бы больше, они бы все равно автоматически складывались бы и выводились.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml

url = 'https://parsinger.ru/html/index1_page_1.html'
response = requests.get(url=url)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
div = soup.find('div','item_card').find_all('p','price')

for txt in div:
    print(txt.text)

sumPrice = 2310+5480+21810+21810+27770+27770+24230+32600
print(sumPrice)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `txt.text` возвращает `str`, вам нужно преобразвать в `int`, но так как у вас там присутствует не только число, нужно сделать замену, `txt.text.replace("руб", "")`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://parsinger.ru/html/index1_page_1.html'
response = requests.get(url=url)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
div = soup.find('div','item_card').find_all('p','price')

sumPrice = 0

for txt in div:
    print(f"Цена: {txt.text}")
    price = int(txt.text.replace("руб", ""))
    sumPrice = sumPrice+price

print(f"Общай сумма: {sumPrice} руб")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://parsinger.ru/html/index1_page_1.html'

response = requests.get(url=url)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

divs = soup.find_all('p', class_='price') 
prices = [price.text.strip(' руб') for price in divs] # создаём список с ценами

print(sum(list(map(int, prices)))) # преобразуем текст к числам и суммируем
```